# Android - How to get a view initialized in onCreate?

Tags: android, handler

I try to get back a view I initialized before in my activity in onCreate(), but I don't know how to do this.

It's look like something like this :

```
public class activityA extends AppCompatActivity {

public ImageView ivImg1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutA);

     ivImg1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
}
```

The image view is empty of any ressource. I create a Handler in an other class :

```
public class firstClass{
    final private imgHandler mHandler = new imgHandler();
    final int KEY = 1;

    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(KEY,R.drawable.face1,0,ivImg1);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

And now I would like to set the first argument `R.drawable.face1` to the ImageView in my Handler :

```
public class imgHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        ImageView viewToSet = (ImageView)msg.obj;
        viewToSet.setImageResource(msg.arg1); //Here is the logcat error
    }
}
```

I result on a java.lang.NullPointerException. I think it's because the object I send in the message is empty. In onCreate the view is inside, but when I call it in the message, the `findViewById`isn't in `ivImg1`.

Class FirstClass is in a new Thread, and class imgHandler is in the UI Thread.

I hope someone can help me.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: "img1" is defined in the "layoutA" right?

Comment: Why not `ivImg1.setImageResource(R.drawable.face1)` just after `findViewById(R.id.img1)`?

Comment: @jak10h: Yes, "img1" is defined in "layoutA".

Comment: @user3161880: because in reality I have many ImageView and many ressource, I choose the ressource and the ImageView I have to connect in many classes (who works in a new thread) and I need to set the ressource with my Handler.

Comment: Could you please post complete `activityA` code, if possible?

Comment: @user3161880: ActivityA contain just onClickListener for all the ImageView it initalized before.